# connecting to sftp server via pysftp with HostKeys

Tags: sftp, ssh-keys, pysftp

I am using pysftp module for connecting to an sftp server. I user the following two commands to skip hostkey file checking:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
```

I still get a warning that says

> "Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\myusername.ssh\known_hosts. 
>   You will need to explicitly load HostKeys
>   (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking
>   (cnopts.hostkeys = None)."

So I would like to load the hostkeys inside the script. But my problem is that I am unable to find the said hostkeys.

I tried connecting to my sftp server via putty but putty terminal closed by itself upon logging in and I don't have any .ssh folder created to see the keys.

Is there any way I can create a hostkey for my sftp server to load inside the script?

Comment: See [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that until you store the hostkey in the host_keys file, you will keep getting the warning. I found out the public key and have saved it inside the host_key. Commented out  "cnopts.hostkeys = None" from my script since it hoskeys are being looked up on my machine. No more warnings now.

Comment: Where we can find the public key on FTP server, bro?

Comment: @python_enthusiast where is this key? you can explain the whole process